# Button color change in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx

This is my code for drawing bus seat. Each `Button` represents a seat drawn in the `GridPane`. I want to change the seat color from green to yellow when someone clicks on the seat. So far I have done this. If I click on the button it prints "hellow world" in output window. But button color doesn't change in the UI. Here is my code:

```
public static GridPane drawBus(int rows, int col, String ss){
    GridPane table = new GridPane();
    table.setHgap(5);
    table.setVgap(5);
    table.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    String seatName;

    if(ss.equals("ROW WISE")||ss.equals("Row Wise")||ss.equals("row wise")){
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){

        for(int j=0;j<col; j++)
        {
        seat=new Button();
        seat.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        seat.setPrefSize(80, 31);

        seatName=numToString(i+1)+(j+1);
        seat.setText(seatName);
        seat.setStyle("-fx-background-color: MediumSeaGreen");


        seat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            seat.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Yellow");
            System.out.println("Hello World!");

        }
        });

        busSeatList.put(seatName, 0);

        //add them to the GridPane
        table.add(seat, j, i); //  (child, columnIndex, rowIndex)

     }


    }
    }
    else
    {
      for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){

        for(int j=0;j<col; j++)
        {
        seat=new Button();
        seat.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        seat.setPrefSize(80, 31);

        seatName=(i+1)+numToString(j+1);
        seat.setText(seatName);
        seat.setStyle("-fx-background-color: MediumSeaGreen");


        seat.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
            //seat.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Yellow");

        }
        });



        busSeatList.put(seatName, 0);
        //add them to the GridPane
        table.add(seat, j, i); //  (child, columnIndex, rowIndex)


       }


    }


    }


    return table;
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use "magic strings". Better use a enum. This way the compiler will complain about typos making the code easier to maintain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easier to use a class that already implements this functionality and use a stylesheet. `ToggleButton` is a class that suits your needs:

```
ToggleButton btn = new ToggleButton("Say 'Hello World'");
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
});

...
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

#### style.css

```css
.toggle-button {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}

.toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}
```

---

BTW: the issue in your code is probably using a field (`seat`) to store the button. This way if you press ***any*** button, the last one created will always be the one modified. Use a `final` local variable declared in the inner loop instead if you want to keep using your implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. For my implementation using `final` local variable worked for me. This function is in my `testControllerClass` for `test` fxml file. Where do I need to get resource from `Style.css` class.

Comment: @WaliurRahman You need to make sure it's included in the classpath at runtime and placed in the same directory as the class file for the class containing the code.

Answer (score 3):

My advice for dynamic style is to use custom PseudoClass and css:

Pseudo class in code:

```
public static final PseudoClass PSEUDO_CLASS_FOO = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("foo");

// ... then in your creation method
// Note using java8 lambda is more concise:
seat.setOnAction(event->{
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
       seat.pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDO_CLASS_FOO, true);

    });
```

In your css:

```
Button:foo {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}
```