# Certain components stacking on top of each other in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to build a [nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram) that looks something like this
[image]

But currently my code displays the clues (the numbers at the top and left side) like this

[image]

The clues are stacked on top of each other, when I want them spaced out into rows.

This is my code so far using JavaFX:

```java
public class PuzzleView implements FXComponent {

  private Controller controller;
  private Pane board;
  private Pane entirePuzzle;
  private VBox[] vertClues;
  private HBox[] horzClues;
  private Pane[][] tiles;

  public PuzzleView(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
  }

  @Override
  public Parent render() {
    entirePuzzle = new Pane(); // grid pane
    initBoard();
    initLabels();
    entirePuzzle.getChildren().add(board);
    return entirePuzzle;
  }

  private void initBoard() {
    board = new Pane();
    int width = controller.getClues().getWidth();
    int height = controller.getClues().getHeight();
    board.setLayoutX(100);
    board.setLayoutY(100);
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        Rectangle clues = new Rectangle();
        clues.setWidth(width);
        clues.setHeight(height);
        clues.setLayoutX(i*(width*50));
        clues.setLayoutY(j*height*50);
        clues.setStroke(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
        clues.setStrokeWidth(2);
        clues.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        board.getChildren().add(clues);
      }
    }

    tiles = new Pane[width][height];
    for (int i=0; i<width; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
        tiles[i][j] = new Pane();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(50, 50);
        rect.setStroke(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
        rect.setStrokeWidth(1);
        rect.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        tiles[i][j].getChildren().add(rect);
        tiles[i][j].setLayoutX(i*50);
        tiles[i][j].setLayoutY(j*50);
        board.getChildren().add(tiles[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }

  private void initLabels() {
    int width = controller.getClues().getWidth();
    int height = controller.getClues().getHeight();
    vertClues = new VBox[height];
    horzClues = new HBox[width];
    Clues clue = controller.getClues();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      horzClues[i] = new HBox();
      horzClues[i].setLayoutX(100 + i * width);

      for (int j=0; j<controller.getClues().getColCluesLength(); j++) {
        horzClues[i].setSpacing(width);
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(clue.getColClues(i)[j]));
        label.minHeight(25);
        label.minWidth(25);
        horzClues[i].getChildren().add(label);
      }

      entirePuzzle.getChildren().add(horzClues[i]);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      vertClues[i] = new VBox();
      vertClues[i].setLayoutY(100 + i * height);
      for (int j=0; j<controller.getClues().getRowCluesLength(); j++) {
        Label label = new Label(String.valueOf(clue.getRowClues(i)[j]));
        label.minHeight(25);
        label.minWidth(25);
        vertClues[i].getChildren().add(label);
      }

      entirePuzzle.getChildren().add(vertClues[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

`FXComponent` is an interface I made that just has a `render()` method that returns a component object that I can put together in a different class. `controller` is another class I made that allows me to access the properties and other functions of the puzzle itself.

Comment: You should be using a `GridPane` for this layout, shouldn't you? By trying to manually build the layout yourself, you're doing a lot more work than you need to.

Comment: When I tried to change `entirePuzzle` to GridPane, everything got worse and it was all over the place. I tried reading documentation on how to position things and I couldn't get it wrapped around my head and they were all just..kinda stuck there.

Comment: I think rather than reposting your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230053/using-javafx-to-display-a-grid-for-a-nonogram-game), that you deleted, you should have simply edited the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete answer, just a suggestion but hopefully it will help you progress.

I suggest using a [TilePane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#sthref24) for the board where each "tile" is a [ToggleButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html). Refer to [Button color change in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149502/button-color-change-in-javafx) for a way to change the colors of the `ToggleButton`.

Set the "board" as the center `Node` of a [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) and place the row hints as the left `Node` and the column hints as the top `Node`.

Note that the below code is based on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67230053/using-javafx-to-display-a-grid-for-a-nonogram-game) (that you deleted).

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Nonogram extends Application {
    private static final int  COLS = 5;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(createBoard());
        root.setLeft(createLeftPane());
        root.setTop(createTopPane());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TilePane createBoard() {
        TilePane board = new TilePane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        board.setPrefRows(COLS);
        ObservableList<Node> children = board.getChildren();
        for (int row = 0; row < COLS; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
                ToggleButton b = new ToggleButton();
                children.add(b);
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    private Label createColumnLabel(String text) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced"));
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setMinWidth(17);
        label.setPrefWidth(17);
        label.setMaxWidth(17);
        return label;
    }

    private VBox createLeftPane() {
        VBox leftPane = new VBox(createRowLabel("  3"),
                                 createRowLabel("  2"),
                                 createRowLabel("  2"),
                                 createRowLabel("  1"),
                                 createRowLabel("1 1"));
        return leftPane;
    }

    private Label createRowLabel(String text) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced"));
        label.setMinHeight(25);
        label.setPrefHeight(25);
        label.setMaxHeight(25);
        return label;
    }

    private HBox createTopPane() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(22, 27);
        rect.setFill(Color.AZURE);
        HBox topPane = new HBox(rect,
                                createColumnLabel("1 1"),
                                createColumnLabel("  2"),
                                createColumnLabel("  4"),
                                createColumnLabel("  2"),
                                createColumnLabel("  3"));
        return topPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There is probably a better way to determine the sizes and alignment of the "hints", but I was too lazy to look for it.

Here is a screen capture of the running app.

[image: screen capture of running app]

Comment: This is great, thank you! Follow up question..how would I use a nested for loop to print out the clues from my `controller`?  I currently have something like [this](https://pastebin.com/HyNDMYsx) for `createTopPane()` but they display next to each other rather than separating into 2 rows like it should.

Comment: Basically you want to create a string representation of each clue to use as the text for a `Label`. Post a new question. Provide a [mcve] by posting a sample set of clues and indicating what your desired result is, i.e. the string representation of each clue. (And if this answer is _great_, maybe you would consider accepting it, or at least up-voting it?)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to use a 2x2 GridPane to hold the row clues, column clues and the puzzle grid with the top left section left empty.  All three of these sections will in turn have their own GridPane.  So you have 3 GridPanes inside of the 2x2 screen GridPane.

Then use row and column constraints to control the alignment of everything, and to make the puzzle GridPane square.  I've carved it out into methods so that the data loading stuff is clearly separated from the layout part.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Nonogram extends Application {
    private final GridPane puzzleGrid = new GridPane();
    private final GridPane columnClueGrid = new GridPane();
    private final GridPane rowClueGrid = new GridPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane mainGrid = new GridPane();
        mainGrid.add(puzzleGrid, 1, 1);
        mainGrid.add(columnClueGrid, 1, 0);
        mainGrid.add(rowClueGrid, 0, 1);
        configureGrids();
        loadData();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainGrid, 300, 270));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void configureGrids() {
        columnClueGrid.getColumnConstraints()
                      .addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> createColumnConstraints(30)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        rowClueGrid.getColumnConstraints()
                   .addAll(IntStream.range(0, 3).mapToObj(x -> createColumnConstraints(18)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        rowClueGrid.getRowConstraints().addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> new RowConstraints(27)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        puzzleGrid.getRowConstraints().addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> new RowConstraints(27)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        puzzleGrid.getColumnConstraints()
                  .addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> createColumnConstraints(30)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        puzzleGrid.gridLinesVisibleProperty().set(true);
    }

    private ColumnConstraints createColumnConstraints(double width) {
        ColumnConstraints results = new ColumnConstraints(width);
        results.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
        return results;
    }

    private void loadData() {
        String[][] rowClues =
                {{"1", "1", "1", "2", "", "2", "", ""}, {"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "", "6"}, {"3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "7", "1"}};
        String[][] columnClues =
                {{"1", "1", "", "2", "", "", "", "1"}, {"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "1"}, {"1", "3", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3"}};
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                columnClueGrid.add(new Text(columnClues[row][col]), col, row);
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                rowClueGrid.add(new Text(rowClues[col][row]), col, row);
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                puzzleGrid.add(new Text("X"), col, row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the screen ends up looking like this:

[image]

After seeing the comment with the example nonogram, I couldn't resist turning it into a fully working screen.  So I replaced the "X" in each square with a rectangle, with a click that toggles the opacity between 0 and 1:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Nonogram extends Application {
    private final GridPane puzzleGrid = new GridPane();
    private final GridPane columnClueGrid = new GridPane();
    private final GridPane rowClueGrid = new GridPane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane mainGrid = new GridPane();
        mainGrid.add(puzzleGrid, 1, 1);
        mainGrid.add(columnClueGrid, 1, 0);
        mainGrid.add(rowClueGrid, 0, 1);
        configureGrids();
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                puzzleGrid.add(createRectangle(), col, row);
            }
        }
        loadData();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainGrid, 300, 270));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node createRectangle() {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(26, 23, Color.TEAL);
        rectangle.setOpacity(0);
        rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
            rectangle.setOpacity(1 - rectangle.getOpacity());
        });
        return rectangle;
    }

    private void configureGrids() {
        columnClueGrid.getColumnConstraints()
                      .addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> createColumnConstraints(30)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        rowClueGrid.getColumnConstraints()
                   .addAll(IntStream.range(0, 3).mapToObj(x -> createColumnConstraints(18)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        rowClueGrid.getRowConstraints().addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> new RowConstraints(27)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        puzzleGrid.getRowConstraints().addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> new RowConstraints(27)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        puzzleGrid.getColumnConstraints()
                  .addAll(IntStream.range(0, 8).mapToObj(x -> createColumnConstraints(30)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        puzzleGrid.gridLinesVisibleProperty().set(true);
    }

    private ColumnConstraints createColumnConstraints(double width) {
        ColumnConstraints results = new ColumnConstraints(width);
        results.setHalignment(HPos.CENTER);
        return results;
    }

    private void loadData() {
        String[][] rowClues =
                {{"1", "1", "1", "2", "", "2", "", ""}, {"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "", "6"}, {"3", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "7", "1"}};
        String[][] columnClues =
                {{"1", "1", "", "2", "", "", "", "1"}, {"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "1"}, {"1", "3", "3", "2", "3", "2", "3", "3"}};
        for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                columnClueGrid.add(new Text(columnClues[row][col]), col, row);
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
                rowClueGrid.add(new Text(rowClues[col][row]), col, row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So now it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: How could the program change if I stored the clues differently? For example, for this example [puzzle](https://www.puzzle-nonograms.com/?e=MDo5MDMsMDA3), my row and column clues are stores like [this](https://pastebin.com/MX4xa6ZZ).

Comment: That's just data handling, which is why I split out loadData() by itself, since it really has nothing to do with the layout.  Fill the rows and columns how ever you want, it doesn't change anything in the structure of the GridPanes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's doing exactly what you're asking it to. Like @Zephyr said, `GridPane` layout would save you a lot of manual positioning.

You need to set the positions differently. They look identical to me.
Yet
it will still cause you issues in the long run. If you eventually want to change window sizes, the layout manager would take care of that work for you.