# Javafx - Changing the color of a buttom

Tags: java, javafx, colors, background-color

I am a java beginner and i tried to lock it up and tried diffrent command but none of them worked.

I want to change the Background Color of Button for example from red to green.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149502/button-color-change-in-javafx

Comment: "_but none of them worked_" – Then you should provide a [mre] demonstrating what didn't work (by [edit]ing your question). Clearly there are ways to change the background color of a button, otherwise those approaches you found while researching would not have worked for everyone else. This means there must be a mistake in your code that we could possibly help you with—if we could see it.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will set a buttons color to red:

```
Button button = new Button("My Button");
button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff0000; ");
```

If you need any more help with buttons you can refer to the documentation here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setStyle-java.lang.String-